# Eigenfunction for an ODE with initial condition and corresponding eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I am just wondering for the ODE
$$y^{\prime\prime} - \lambda y = 0,$$
with the given condition $y'(0)=0$.

> Why is it that when $\lambda=0$, the eigenfunction is found to be $y_0=1$? i.e. the solution to that ODE when $\lambda=0$ is $y=1$.

Could someone explain why?

Also if the eigenfunction is $1$, does it mean any multiple of $1$ is also a solution? such as $y =1, y =-3, y =5, y = 9192, y =-1, y = 0$ (another question: does $y = 0$ actually give a valid solution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes because if you solve the ODE you get:

$$\begin{eqnarray} y'' - \lambda y & = & 0 \\
y'' & = & 0 & \text{since } \lambda = 0 \\
\int y'' \ dx & = & \int 0 \ dx \\
y' & = & A \\
& = & 0 & \text{since } y'(0) = 0 \\
\int y' \ dx & = & \int 0 \ dx \\
y & = & B \end{eqnarray}$$

So the eigenfunction of the second derivative operator, with the given boundary condition, is *any* constant function, as you suspected. (Without the boundary condition, the eigenfunctions would be of the form $y = Ax + B$.) It is common to choose a *representative* eigenfunction from which we can parametrise the full set, so choosing $y = 1$ just makes the numbers look nicer (and similarly, the family of functions $y = Ax + B$ can be written as a linear combination of $y = x$ and $y = 1$, although we could just as equally choose $y = 43x + 9$ and $y = 17 - x$ or some other pair of linearly independent equations).

As for your last question - does $y = 0$ give a valid solution? The answer is yes - if you differentiate it twice, you get $y'' = 0$ which clearly satisfies the original DE. We wouldn't choose it as our representative function just because you can't get any of the other solutions from it by linear combinations.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of $y''=0$ subject to $y'(0)=0$ is the constant function $y\equiv C$. Any constant $C$ will do.